# How to artifically carbonate sparkling elderflower?

Tags: carbonation

I'm brewing a sparkling elderflower drink that relies on the natural yeasts present on the flowers/stalks to carbonate the drink after it has been transferred to bottles (swing-top type). There is sufficient sugar in the recipe, and this has worked for me in the past, but I've read that this sometimes doesn't work. Is there a way to carbonate an already-bottled drink that is flat, without affecting alcohol content or flavour?

The ingredients for 4.5 litres is:

- 7 elderflower heads
- 750 g sugar
- 2 lemons
- 2 table spoons wine vinegar

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume this is not a very foamy beverage, and say: carbonate it like homemade [soda](http://www.sodastream.com/).

BTW- carbonation makes a drink more tart, so the flavor will change a little.

Comment: Thanks for the link - I thought there must be something like this on the market.

Answer (score 1):

In short: not with what you want to use. The carbonation (CO2) is formed as a by-product of alcohol forming from the yeast eating the sugar (less sugar and more alcohol = altered flavour)

There is a way of doing it, using compressed CO2. This requires a carbonator and CO2 cartridges. It is worth the investment if you want to use the carbonator a lot, but if it's only to save one batch, I (poor) would consider drinking it flat